# Are there options to change alert vibrations, like changing ringtones?

Tags: 8.0, vibration

Since getting my Windows phone, I've noticed that I seem to more easily miss text messages and other alerts. I personally prefer to never use a ringer, but the vibrations used by default on this phone ([Lumia 920](http://www.nokia.com/us-en/products/phone/lumia920/)) seem to be very short and subtle. They're not nearly long or strong enough to grab my attention most of the time.

On my previous phone ([Samsung Rugby II](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SGH-A847ZAAATT)) I could change the vibrations used for each alert type so that they were distinct from one another and fit my preference. Is there such an option for Windows phones?

Comment: I really don't know if it works but maybe the vibration is related to the sound you choose.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change vibrations at the moment. They are different for each alert type though - a calendar reminder is one short vibration followed by one long, an incoming phone call is one short followed by one long, twice and repeating.. etc.